# How to assign values to the children of a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image][image][image]I have a prefab that has Name of the employee which is a button,of which I need to change the text component of the button, a picture of the employee and another image.

I need to be able to assign values to these children as I am creating multiple instances of the prefab for each employee.

How would I do this?

I have already tried transform.find

```
public void instantiateButtons()
{
    Vector3 positionOfRefObj = new Vector3(0, 150, 0);
    Debug.Log(positionOfRefObj);
    //GameObject enemy = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    //GameObject newprefeab =Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(positionOfRefObj.x,positionOfRefObj.y,positionOfRefObj.z), Quaternion.identity);
    GameObject enemy = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, positionOfRefObj.y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    positionOfRefObj = enemy.transform.position;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        enemy = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0,-40+positionOfRefObj.y,0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        positionOfRefObj= enemy.transform.position;

        enemy.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);


    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have already tried transform.find"_; then what happens?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if I did it in the right format. I used transform.find to assign the child to a gameObject. but that results in a error. cannor convert transform to gameobject

Comment: That should be [easy to fix](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html). Transforms aren't game objects, they're Transforms (but all transforms have a reference to their game object).

Comment: so you mean,I can access it by using             child.transform= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform;
? but then I cant assign to transform of a gameObject

Comment: `Transform` is a component on `GameObject`. You need to attach the child `GameObject` to the parent `GameObject`, then manipulate the `Transform` as necessary. You might be doing too many things at once.

Comment: but how do I get the child game object ? I need to be able to manipulate the details of the three chiildren of the parent. If its okay. could you show me how?

Comment: What variables are you trying to set and what values do you want to set them to? Which objects here are the children? Your question mentions things like employees and pictures but your code doesn't show any of this. It would probably help your question be a lot clearer if you included some screenshots of the object hierarchy and components you're working with. Right now everything is very unclear.

Comment: The prefab has 3 children.

nameOfTheEmployee
photo
another image that shows avaialability

Comment: I have also added the screenshot of the object structure